# Pass arguments to a Python module in Mojo?

Tags: mojolang

I have a python module : myScript.py.
Normally, I run it like this

```
python3 myScript.py -i example.jpg
```

I want to pass this argument to this python modules's main function

```
from python import Python
fn use_my_module() raises:
    Python.add_to_path(".")
    let mypython = Python.import_module("myScript.py")
    # myPython is normally called by 'python3 myScript.py -i input.jpg'
    let c = mypython() # How do i add a pass the "input.jpg" to main??
    print(c)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have myScript.py and main.mojo in the same folder:

body of myScript.py:

```py
import sys
def main(args=[""]):
    return args[0]

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

body of main.mojo:

```
from python import Python

fn main() raises:
    Python.add_to_path(".")
    let mypython = Python.import_module("myScript")
    let c = mypython.main(["myPicture.jpg"])
    print(c)
```

run in with

```bash
mojo main.mojo
```